# How do you create a stacked percentage bar chart in R Shiny app with two reactive values?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make a percentage percent bar chart in R with two reactive values. Below is the code that I am using. I keep getting the error "object 'race' not found" and "object 'gender' not found". However, both "race" and "gender" are in the dataframe "filtered_data()". Do you know how I can fix this?

Here is the tab panel:

```
tabPanel(title = "Comparison Bar Plot",
                                                    h1("Bar Chart"),
                                                     h3("Adjust"),
                                                     selectInput(inputId = "AxisX", label = "X Axis Variable",
                                                                 choices = c("Race", "Gender"),
                                                                 selected = "Race"),
                                                     selectInput(inputId = "AxisY", label = "Y Axis Variable",
                                                                 choices = c("Race", "Gender"),
                                                                 selected = "Gender"),
                                                     plotlyOutput("comparisonbarplot")
                                            )
```

And here is the output:

```
    output$comparisonbarplot <- renderPlotly({
  filtered_data() %>% group_by(switch(input$AxisX, Race=race,Gender=gender), switch(input$AxisY, Race=race,Gender=gender)) %>%
    summarise(count=n()) %>% 
    mutate(perc = count/sum(count)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = switch(input$AxisX, Race=race,Gender=gender), y = perc*100, fill=switch(input$AxisY, Race=race,Gender=gender))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values =cbPalette) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity") +
    xlab("Race/Ethnicity") +
    ylab("Percent") +
    labs(title = "Race/Ethnicity and Gender of Defendants \n in Dutchess County Courts Starting Fall 2018", fill = "Gender:")+
    theme_economist() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can return a string in `switch` and then use `group_by` with `across`

```
 output$comparisonbarplot <- renderPlotly({
   fstgrp <- switch(input$AxisX, 
                              Race="race",
                              Gender="gender")
   scndgrp <- switch(input$AxisY,
                             Race="race",
                             Gender="gender")
  filtered_data() %>%
         group_by(across(all_of(c(fstgrp, scndgrp)))) %>%
    summarise(count=n()) %>% 
    mutate(perc = count/sum(count)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = .data[[fstgrp]], y = perc*100,
        fill=.data[[scndgrp]])) +
    scale_fill_manual(values =cbPalette) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity") +
    xlab("Race/Ethnicity") +
    ylab("Percent") +
    labs(title = "Race/Ethnicity and Gender of Defendants \n in Dutchess County Courts Starting Fall 2018", fill = "Gender:")+
    theme_economist() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    })
```